# How would i insert a value of custom field from Advaced Custom Field into shortcode generated by Gravity Forms

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

The situation is the following. I have got a shortcode from gravity forms that read the total entries that a form has recorded. For instance Form 1 - total entries 30. So the shortcode read that data and print out the value of 30.

As the shortcode must be updating for each form created by replacing ID's form I would like to pass a parameter to that shortcode for update that one from advanced custom field post.

the shortcode looks something like this

```
[gravitywp_count formid='']
```

where i must set the form id inside the '',

well , my idea is to have a custom field where the post creator set the number id of the new form created in gravity form and pass it to the shortcode through the custom field

It would be understood as

custom field:

```
Form ID: ID Value
```

then, the value that is posted there, pass to the shortcode once post is updated

```
[gravitywp_count formid='$thefield(form_id)']
```

logically, the shortcode will be placed into a file like single-customposttype.php

So i would like if this approach can be achieved or if there a better way to do this

Thanks to all of you for the help that you can bring me on this.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve the saved meta value and pass it as a parameter to a shortcode.

First option is to get the saved value to a variable, validate it and then concatenate it to a shortcode string you pass to `do_shortcode()`.

```
// get saved meta value
$form_id = get_field('your_key_for_form_id_here');
// make sure we have an ID and it is a number, string or int
if ( $form_id && is_numeric( $form_id ) ) {
  // do_shortcode returns the shortcode html, so you need to echo it yourself
  echo do_shortcode('[gravitywp_count formid=' . $form_id . ']');
}
```

Another option is to just concatenate the meta directly to the shortcode string, if you trust the saved meta value will always be in the right format.

```
echo do_shortcode('[gravitywp_count formid=' . get_field('your_key_for_form_id_here') . ']');
```

You can also skip the shortcode part and just call your callback function directly in your template file.

```
// modify your callback to take form id directly as a parameter
function your_entries_counting_function( int $form_id ) {
  // your code to get the entries count  
}
// get meta data
$form_id = get_field('your_key_for_form_id_here');
// make sure it is what you're expecting
if ( $form_id && is_numeric( $form_id ) ) {
  // pass the ID to your function
  echo your_entries_counting_function( intval( $form_id ) );
}
```

If you're only using ACF for adding the form ID meta field, you could simplify your setup by just registering the metabox yourself with `add_meta_box()` and leaving ACF out of the picture altogether. In this case you would then use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to retrieve the saved form id meta value,

```
$form_id = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'your_key_for_form_id_here', true );
```

Comment: Oh wonderful! thank your for you detailed explanation, i will try as soon as possible and drop you a feedback. Thank you again,

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked the first option! I could resolve the trouble.!

Comment: @JoséDaniel Great, good to hear that it worked. If you haven't done so yet, you can mark my answer accepted so that other members of WPSE community will know that your question is solved.

Comment: Yes, i just already did and marked as solved! Thanks again =)